# mysql how to get the next record where name is more that '<name>'

Tags: php, mysql, string, comparison

I have a register of people.
They are arranged alphabetically.

Given that my current person is called Geoff I want to get someone with a name "higher" than this for example George.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work when I try to get a previous person e.g. Fred.

```
SELECT id
FROM people
WHERE people.name < '".$name."'
ORDER BY people.name ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: *"I have tried the following but it doesn't work when I try to get a previous person e.g. `Fred`."* - What a great name.

Comment: Well, it's a great name for a previous person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using '>' rather than '<'

Comment: You were right the first time. The desc was wrong. As well as the < comparison. Im doing a previous and next user link (with lots of other joins and conditions). So in summary essential skills for programmers: PHP, Mysql, Alphabet and counting. Thank you for your help with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM people
WHERE people.name > '".$name."'
ORDER BY people.name ASC
LIMIT 1
```